# SQL query hourly report?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have a bit of a tough one beating me here. We have a production warehouse where various products are created, we send out a daily production report using the following query but i would like to have this sorted hourly:

(Im trimming down the query to only a few products as its quite a biggie:

```
SET

@DayStart = '2013-10-24 07:00:00',
@DayEnd = '2013-10-24 16:00:00';

SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_container
    WHERE created_timestamp BETWEEN @DayStart AND @DayEnd
    AND container_type_id = '3'

) AS Product1,

(SELECT CONCAT (
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_container
    WHERE created_timestamp BETWEEN @DayStart AND @DayEnd
    AND container_type_id = '10'
    AND status_id = '4'
    ) , ' / ' ,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_container
    WHERE created_timestamp BETWEEN @DayStart AND @DayEnd
    AND container_type_id = '10'
    AND status_id = '6'
    ))
) AS 'Product 1 EOL',

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_container
    WHERE created_timestamp BETWEEN @DayStart AND @DayEnd
    AND container_type_id = '2'
    ) AS 'Product 2',

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_container
    WHERE created_timestamp BETWEEN @DayStart AND @DayEnd
    AND container_type_id = '6'
    ) AS 'Product 3',

(SELECT CONCAT (
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_container
    WHERE created_timestamp BETWEEN @DayStart AND @DayEnd
    AND container_type_id = '9'
    AND status_id = '4'
    ) , ' / ' ,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_container
    WHERE created_timestamp BETWEEN @DayStart AND @DayEnd
    AND container_type_id = '9'
    AND status_id = '6'
    ))
) AS 'Product 3 EOL',

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_container
    WHERE created_timestamp BETWEEN @DayStart AND @DayEnd
    AND container_type_id = '4'
) AS 'Product 4',

(SELECT CONCAT (
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_container
    WHERE created_timestamp BETWEEN @DayStart AND @DayEnd
    AND container_type_id = '8'
    AND status_id = '4'
    ) , ' / ' ,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_container
    WHERE created_timestamp BETWEEN @DayStart AND @DayEnd
    AND container_type_id = '8'
    AND status_id = '6'
    ))
) AS 'Product 4 EOL'
```

What i would like to achieve is to have the above report to run but the output be in 1 hour increments.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Please see below "expected output example"

TIME   |   Product 1   |   Product 1 EOL   |   Product 2   |   Product 3 
07:00  |   12345       |   1 / 1           |   1568789     |   1 / 1 
08:00  |   12345       |   1 / 1           |   1568789     |   1 / 1 
09:00  |   12345       |   1 / 1           |   1568789     |   1 / 1

Comment: *sidenote:* `container_type_id` is String ? why surround the value with quotes?

Comment: Thats just the way i was taught to write sql queries.

Comment: give an example of your expected output.

Comment: Added expected output

Comment: @Stroes: You should write your queries according to _what you know and understand to be true_ based on the documentation, not blindly doing things that you were taught without actually knowing why!

Comment: Please note that you shouldn't be using `BETWEEN` with anything that is logically a variable-precision type (like timestamps) [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) details some SQL Server-specific problems (...I'm aware MySQL is currently less precise), but the concept applies other places too.   I'll also leave you with this piece of information - `BETWEEN` is inclusive (`<=`), so you're selecting the first (recordable) instant of the next day, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a row which contains a LOT of subselects

I would be tempted to recode these to subselect which are then joined into a single row (or just return multiple rows and do the formatted in you display code).

However to split one of those subselects up into hours you could use something like this (not tested):-

```
SELECT StartHour, COUNT(*) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
    ) Sub1
) Sub2
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
ON created_timestamp BETWEEN Sub2.StartHour AND DATE_ADD(Sub2.StartHour, INTERVAL 3599 SECOND)
WHERE created_timestamp BETWEEN @DayStart AND @DayEnd
AND container_type_id = '3'
GROUP BY StartHour
```

This comes up with a range of hour time bands by adding to the start date, then uses that to do a left join against you data (adding 3599 seconds to get the end of the hour time bands), and doing a grouped count, doing GROUP BY on the starting hour.

EDIT

Not tested, but here is one way of doing it:-

```
SELECT StartHour, 
        EndHour, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) AS Product1,
        COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) AS 'Product 1 EOL 1',
        COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS 'Product 1 EOL 2',
        COUNT(DISTINCT d.id) AS 'Product 2',
        COUNT(DISTINCT e.id) AS 'Product 3',
        COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) AS 'Product 3 EOL 1',
        COUNT(DISTINCT g.id) AS 'Product 3 EOL 2',
        COUNT(DISTINCT h.id) AS 'Product 4',
        COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) AS 'Product 4 EOL 1',
        COUNT(DISTINCT j.id) AS 'Product 4 EOL 2'
FROM 
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
    ) Sub1
) Sub2
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container a
ON a.created_timestamp BETWEEN Sub2.StartHour AND Sub2.EndHour
AND a.container_type_id = '3'
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container b
ON b.created_timestamp BETWEEN Sub2.StartHour AND Sub2.EndHour
AND b.container_type_id = '10'
AND b.status_id = '4'
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container c
ON c.created_timestamp BETWEEN Sub2.StartHour AND Sub2.EndHour
AND c.container_type_id = '10'
AND c.status_id = '6'
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container d
ON d.created_timestamp BETWEEN Sub2.StartHour AND Sub2.EndHour
AND d.container_type_id = '2'
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container e
ON e.created_timestamp BETWEEN Sub2.StartHour AND Sub2.EndHour
AND e.container_type_id = '6'
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container f
ON f.created_timestamp BETWEEN Sub2.StartHour AND Sub2.EndHour
AND f.container_type_id = '9'
AND f.status_id = '4'
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container g
ON g.created_timestamp BETWEEN Sub2.StartHour AND Sub2.EndHour
AND g.container_type_id = '9'
AND g.status_id = '6'
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container h
ON h.created_timestamp BETWEEN Sub2.StartHour AND Sub2.EndHour
AND h.container_type_id = '4'
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container i
ON i.created_timestamp BETWEEN Sub2.StartHour AND Sub2.EndHour
AND i.container_type_id = '8'
AND i.status_id = '4'
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container j
ON j.created_timestamp BETWEEN Sub2.StartHour AND Sub2.EndHour
AND j.container_type_id = '8'
AND j.status_id = '6'
GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
```

This is doing 1 subselect to get all the hour time bands, then joining the tables back to get the counts. However using so many COUNT(DISTINCT )) type statements might not perform that well.

Probably be possible to do the joins to get the hour ranges in each of the subselects that are then joined back, which might be better.

Note that I have brought back 2 columns for the columns that previously had 2 values split by a /.

Possibly slightly better (but also possibly slightly worse):-

```
SELECT Product1.rec_cnt AS Product1,
        CONCAT(Product1EOL1.rec_cnt, ' / ', Product1EOL2.rec_cnt) AS 'Product 1 EOL',
        Product2.rec_cnt AS 'Product 2',
        Product3.rec_cnt AS 'Product 3',
        CONCAT(Product3EOL1.rec_cnt, ' / ', Product3EOL2.rec_cnt) AS 'Product 3 EOL',
        Product4.rec_cnt AS 'Product 4',
        CONCAT(Product4EOL1.rec_cnt, ' / ', Product4EOL2.rec_cnt) AS 'Product 4 EOL'
FROM
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '3'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '10'
    AND status_id = '4'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product1EOL1
ON Product1.StartHour = Product1EOL1.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product1EOL1.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '10'
    AND status_id = '6'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product1EOL2
ON Product1.StartHour = Product1EOL2.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product1EOL2.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '2'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product2
ON Product1.StartHour = Product2.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product2.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '6'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product3
ON Product1.StartHour = Product3.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product3.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '9'
    AND status_id = '4'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product3EOL1
ON Product1.StartHour = Product3EOL1.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product3EOL1.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '9'
    AND status_id = '6'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product3EOL2
ON Product1.StartHour = Product3EOL2.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product3EOL2.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '4'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product4
ON Product4.StartHour = Product3.StartHour AND Product4.EndHour = Product3.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '8'
    AND status_id = '4'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product4EOL1
ON Product1.StartHour = Product4EOL1.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product4EOL1.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.id) AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '8'
    AND status_id = '6'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product4EOL2
ON Product1.StartHour = Product4EOL2.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product4EOL2.EndHour
```

Comment: Hi wouldnt the above then just be for one of the products? FYI i am not the most gifted when it comes to sql scripting, but keen to learn.

Comment: Yes that is for just one of the selects, and you would need to do similar for all the products. But this is bringing back multiple rows, so you really need to do this on joined subselects. I will have more of a play if it would help.

Comment: i have had a look at the query and does exactly what i need it to do! thanks, just need to figure out how to join the subselects as you stated to have all the data in a single row. this is a bit new territory for me so the advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not tested yet, but added a new possible query.

Comment: tested the above, but seems to just keep on running as no end time/date is defined?

Comment: also just for interest sake, can you count on any of the fields in the table? we dont have an "id" field, have an container_id. Yip i know the okes that designed the DB made a bit of a mess

Comment: You do need the @DayStart defined (the end time is calculated). I just used id as an assumed column name for the unique identifier on that table; if container_id is the unique identifier then you should use that instead (due to the joins it could land up with the same row multiple times, the COUNT(DISTINCT id) is to just ensure it only counts each one once)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39902/discussion-between-stroes-and-kickstart)

Comment: you sir are a SUPERSTAR!!! lol query works perfect when defining the startdate. just not showing the timestamp in the first column anymore